# error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error

Tags: ssl, curl

So I have this strange error(strange cause i dont know what is this) that i got in my laravel app.

```
"error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error"
```

I've done a lot of research about the error and I still can't solve the issue. But some suggested to put something on tomcat.

Comment: Lots of problems look like this and you have to few details provided to debug the problem. Might be SNI, might be something else. See http://noxxi.de/howto/ssl-debugging.html for either how to debug SSL problems yourself or at least how to provide enough information so that can others help you.